# how to get date and time in java like this 02-Oct-12 12:58:20 AM

Tags: java, datetime

i have tried some thing like this

```
package com.poc;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class GetCurrentDateTime {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       //get current date time with Date()
       Date date = new Date();
       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

       //get current date time with Calendar()
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

  }
}
```

and my out put is : `2013-01-07 17:12:27` but want the output to be like this `2013-Jan-07 17:12:27 PM`

how to do this in java?

Best Regards

Comment: Well, look at the argument you're passing into `SimpleDateFormat` at the moment, and look at the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation for what's allowed. Which specific part of that are you stuck on?

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/java/javadate/month-format.shtml

Comment: Also note that the date format in your *title* ("02-Oct-12") is different to the one in your text ("2013-Jan-07"). Which do you want?

Comment: [Link which has all the formats of date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and comments, I got the answer now and I don't know the reason for down voting for this question. Thanks to the guy who down voted and forgot to give reason for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your format should be

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss a");
```

**07-Jan-13 07:20:02 PM**

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss");
```

**07-Jan-13 19:20:02**

Answer (score 3):

Your format should be

```
yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss a
```

Comment: There is that, but also the locale if the OP really wants, say, `Feb` and not `Fév`.

Comment: @fge true, but OP dint mention about locale in the question, however good suggestion and one must keep that in mind though  :)

Answer (score 2):

use this instead:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`Class SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> **Month**: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.

So `MM` is iterpreted as number and `MMM` or more is interpreted as text (i.e. month *name*)